# Hardware Keyboard Event

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can anyone tell me how to detect when the hardware keyboard is used and when the soft-key-pad is used? Or is there any event which tells that the hardware keypad is shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Mango, the hardware keyboard detection can now be done - see:

- IsKeyboardDeployed - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.iskeyboarddeployed(v=VS.92).aspx
- IsKeyboardPresent - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.iskeyboardpresent%28v=VS.92%29.aspx
- KeyboardDeployedChanged - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.keyboarddeployedchanged(v=VS.92).aspx

from [Is there any way to detect if there's a hardware keyboard on the phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595090/is-there-any-way-to-detect-if-theres-a-hardware-keyboard-on-the-phone/7595180#7595180)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't currently anything exposed to reliably detect this.

Jaime Rodriguez explores a partial solution here and advises against using it in summary.

[Guessing if the SIP is visible in a Windows Phone application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/05/guessing-if-the-sip-is-visible-in-a-windows-phone-application.aspx)

Mostly people want to detect this to customise layout to make accept / cancel type functions accessible. In that respect, the Application Bar can be used successfully.