# Is there any way to detect if there's a hardware keyboard on the phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I've seen other questions like [Hardware Keyboard Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883168/hardware-keyboard-event)

But not seen this for Mango... is there any way to find out if the phone has a hardware keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DeviceStatus.IsKeyboardPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.iskeyboardpresent%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) Property

> [DeviceStatus.IsKeyboardPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.iskeyboardpresent%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
>   Indicates whether the device contains a physical hardware keyboard.

Comment: Thanks - I did search but couldn't find it. Also now seen IsKeyboardDeployed there too. Thanks.