# WP7 - Check for QWERTY Keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm building an app for WP7 and it occurred to me that the HTC Arrive has a sliding QWERTY keyboard. Is there a way to check for this in XAML and/or C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it using

```
bool hasHardwareKeyboard = Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.IsKeyboardPresent;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.iskeyboardpresent(v=vs.92) or [Hardware Keyboard Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883168/hardware-keyboard-event)